# How to tell if a sample comes from a distribution with infinite mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

I observe a sample from a distribution that I expect to be the hitting time

$$\tau = \inf\{t>0| X(t)>a\}$$

where $X(t)$ is a Lévy process with $X(0)=0$ and $a$ is some constant. $X$ is not a Brownian motion and the experimental fit to the [Lévy distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_distribution) is poor.

However, I do not need to know the exact formula for the law of $\tau$. For my needs I only need to know that the expectation of $\tau$ is infinite (as in the case of tau for a Brownian motion). Is it possible to formulate and test this as a statistical hypothesis?

Comment: As a general thing, it might be rather tricky; how might one distinguish (as an example) a random variable which has a Pareto distribution with $\alpha=1$ from one with $\alpha=1+\varepsilon$?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2504/test-for-finite-variance/2511#2511 for the same question about testing for a finite variance.